# Why close warning appears in Microsoft Edge?

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge

I'm working on a basic oauth authentication prototype and I have a HTML (called `parent.html`) opening a child window to serve the purpose. The child window would be redirected to the provider website and then to my registered page. My registered page would call `window.close();` using javascript to close the child window.

But when I tried my prototype in Microsoft Edge, I noticed a close warning every time javascript tried to close the child window. I tested other websites which use popup window for oauth authentication like dropbox, I didn't see the same close warning when authentication was done and the child window was about to close.

Does anyone know why (and in what circumstance) does Edge show this warning dialog? Any information would be useful and appreciated. Thanks.

[image: Screenshot of the close warning]

Comment: Who/what opened this window with the warning? You or javascript?

Comment: You can only automatically close windows with JavaScript which were opened using `window.open`.

Comment: The child window was opened by parent.html using child = window.open(), but after some redirections the child window loses window.opener reference and parent window loses child reference as well. Not sure if it's the reason.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the popup blocker and automated script blocker features in MS Edge. Basically these two features will try to block any script that runs automatically without user's actions during the loading of the page.

For example, these two scripts will be blocked in MS Edge (they work in IE):

```
var w = window.open("page.htm"); //w will be null.

window.close(); //displays a warning.
```

The same two lines will work if you place them in a function and call them from a click event of a button, for example.

---

## solution:

Create a function in the main window to close the popup window, and in the popup window call that function and pass it a reference to the popup window:

```
// in main window
function closePopup(w) {
    w.close();
}

// in popup window
opener.closePopup(this);
```